# Postgres partition/group by value change

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I would like to build a query which groups data not by value itself, but by the fact that the value changes between rows. I would appreciate any help with it! Here is an example:

Assuming I have a table with this structure:

```
create table events (
  event_time timestamp, 
  source_id integer references source(id),
  metric integer,
  flagged boolean
);
```

and following sample data:

```
source_id | event_time | metric | flagged
-----------------------------------------
1         | 8:00       | 1      | t
1         | 8:10       | 15     | f
1         | 8:20       | 7      | t
1         | 8:30       | 3      | t
1         | 8:40       | 6      | f
1         | 8:50       | 10     | t 
2         | 9:00       | 5      | t
```

I would like to query average value of `metric`, for sub-groups of the groups by `source_id`, but grouping those sub-groups by the fact that `flagged` doesn't change from one row to the next, provided that data is ordered. That is, in the example, above, I don't mean to `group by source_id, flagged`, as this would only give two groups for each `source_id`, but group consecutive rows, ordered by time, where `flagged` has the same value in adjacent rows. That is, I would like to have following groups:

```
group_number | source_id | flagged | avg(metric)
------------------------------------------------
1            | 1         | t       | 1            -- group includes entry for 8:00 only
2            | 1         | f       | 15           -- entry for 8:15 only
3            | 1         | t       | 5            -- entries on 8:20 & 8:30, (7+3)/2
4            | 1         | f       | 6            -- entry for 8:40 only
5            | 1         | t       | 10           -- entry for 8:50 only
6            | 2         | t       | 5            -- 9:00 from source_id = 2
```

`group_number` is not needed in the output, it is here only to make the case clearer. Furthermore, I don't need the entries which are not `flagged` - basically they only serve to split the groups.

I was trying to do this with partitioning and `ranks` and `lags`, but to no avail so far. Would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  One solution uses the difference of row numbers.

```
select source_id, flagged, avg(metric)
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by source_id order by event_time) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by source_id, flagged order by event_time) as seqnum_2
      from events e
     ) e
group by source_id, flagged, (seqnum_1 - seqnum_2);
```

The reason this works is a bit tricky to explain.  I find that if you run the subquery, you'll see how the difference between the row numbers identifies the groups of adjacent rows with the same flag.

Comment: Thanks for giving the name of the problem - now that I know it is "gaps-and-islands" problem I found a lot of articles on the subject out there. And, solution works perfectly for my case, thanks.